# Generate TypeScript Interfaces from Schema by Apollo generate and custom but too long (time) - around 30.000 lines take about 1 hour

Tags: typescript, graphql, schema, apollo, nestjs

I want to use GraphQLDefinitionsFactory `from '@nestjs/graphql'` to generate TypeScript interfaces for me based on the queries from my Prisma server and schema graphql by custom like type query, mutation, type Input...

**Issue**: Schema around 6.000 - 7.000 lines takes about 5 minutes, which is no problem. But with schema with around 30.000 lines take more than 1 hour, which is way too long.

I have tried this code:

```
import { GqlModuleOptions, GqlOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { join } from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class GraphqlOptions implements GqlOptionsFactory {

  createGqlOptions(): Promise<GqlModuleOptions> | GqlModuleOptions {
    return {
      context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
      typePaths: ['./src/*/*.graphql', './generated/*.graphql'], // path for gql schema files
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      resolverValidationOptions: {
        requireResolversForResolveType: false,
      },
      definitions: {
        // will generate .ts types from gql schema files
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.schema.generated.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      debug: true,
      introspection: true,
      playground: true,
    };
  }
}
```

Then, I start server from the terminal:

```
[Nest] 8048   - 03/12/2020, 12:25:04 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +723ms
[Nest] 8048   - 03/12/2020, 12:25:04 PM   [InstanceLoader] PrismaModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 8048   - 03/12/2020, 12:25:04 PM   [InstanceLoader] UserModule dependencies initialized +4ms
[Nest] 8048   - 03/12/2020, 12:25:04 PM   [InstanceLoader] GraphQLModule dependencies initialized +1ms
```

Second way :

```
import { GraphQLDefinitionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';

const definitionsFactory = new GraphQLDefinitionsFactory();
definitionsFactory.generate({
  typePaths: ['./src/*/*.graphql', './generated/*.graphql'], // path for gql schema files
  path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.schema.ts'),
  outputAs: 'class',
});
```

*run command : * `ts-node src/generate-typings.ts` by guide document from nestjs: *https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#schema-first*

I don't know why the `generate` takes that much time.
If you know, can you explain this to me? Is there a way to improve performance of `generate` or maybe I am wrong and I need to fix something?
If you want more infomation, please comment below, I will provide.
Thank you so much.